# Как сконвертировать i32 в usize Rust

Tags: массивы, rust

Всем доброго времени суток. Давайте поясню суть проблемы.
Имеются два значения: i:i32 и j:i32. При этом нужно сделать следующее:

```
...  table[i as usize][j as usize].to_string() ...
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы численно значения были те же самые, но при этом вместо i32 - usize. Буду очень сильно благодарен за решение данного вопроса.

Comment: А если там отрицательное число?

Comment: А что делает "i as usize", если i - i32?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, напиши после получения i и j:

```
let i:usize = i as usize;
let j:usize = j as usize;
```

Тогда у тебя i и j будут usize.